# Read data in line into string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need user input 3 names separated by space, for example:

```
Please enter 3 names: name1 name2 name3
```

then I want to store it to array with 3 string elements as those 3 names, How to do that, please **suggest me some method of STRING in java** since I'm often use C++, **I'm not asking for code**, thank you!

```
String array[] = new String[3];
System.out.print("Please enter 3 names: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = in.nextLine();
//do domething
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect place for

[`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner` has a method named `next` that gives you next word* instead of next line. That should be a sufficient hint.

<sub>* Not entirely true. The default delimiter is whitespace. If you change that, you would be getting tokens separated by that particular delimiter.</sub>

---

Another way: Just split the string by supplying the characters to be used for splitting.

```
"hello j and k".split(" ") => { "hello", "j", "and", "k" }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    String array[] = new String[3];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        String input = in.nextLine();
        array[i] = input;
    }
```

Comment: **I'm not asking for code** part didn't say something to you?